# Function Download in Yii2

Tags: file, download, yii2

```
public function actionUnduh($id) {
        $download = PstkIdentifikasi::findOne($id);
        $path = Yii::getAlias('../web/bukti/') . $download->bukti;

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            //return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($download->pre_paper,@file_get_contents($path));
            return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);
        }
    }
```

I need to download file from folder web/bukti, the code not error but the code doesn't work, Anyone can help me :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public function actionUnduh($id) 
{ 
    $download = PstkIdentifikasi::findOne($id); 
    $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/bukti/'.$download->bukti;

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path, 'File name here');
    }
}
```

Refer below:

[Yii2 Aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html)

[Yii2 sendFile()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail)

Comment: please always check if `$download` is not empty before using it. It is not dangerous here, but it could be somewhere else.

Comment: Can we update the file name which will be downloaded without change original file name?

Comment: @vishuB Thank you. It's working as per requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you can write an action in SiteController.php  like this:

```
public function actionDownload()
{
    $file=Yii::$app->request->get('file');
    $path=Yii::$app->request->get('path');
    $root=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').$path.$file;
    if (file_exists($root)) {
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($root);
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException("{$file} is not found!");
    }
}
```

then you can call this function anywhere:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/download','path'=>'/upload/files/','file'=>'filename.pdf'])
```

Be careful your files must be in this directory:

> "backend/web/upload/files/filename.pdf"

or

> "frontend/web/upload/files/filename.pdf"